# Safari brower on Ubuntu

Tags: testing, cross-browser, browser-testing

I need to test something on Safari, and right now I do not have safari browser and using ubuntu. What can i do?

I tries using PlayonLinux but it installs the oldest version which isnt even supporting the product homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Safari 5.1.7 was the last version released for Windows, therefor this is the latest version you can use with PlayOnLinux.

Take a look at [DarlingHQ](https://www.darlinghq.org/).

DarlingHQ is an macOS translation layer for linux that lets you run macOS software. After installing you can test your software with the latest version of Safari.